# Combining sql select queries

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different queries, which both return results similar to below. For example

```
SELECT value
     , date_format( statdate, "%Y-%m-%d" ) AS testdate
FROM stats
WHERE name LIKE 'myname1'
    AND date >= "2014-09-20"
    and date < "2014-09-24"
GROUP BY 2;

SELECT value
    , date_format( statdate, "%Y-%m-%d" ) AS testdate
FROM stats
WHERE name LIKE 'myname2'
    AND date >= "2014-09-20"
    and date < "2014-09-24"
GROUP BY 2;
```

Information comes from the same table, but part of it is a different WHERE (with the date being the field which is the same in both).

Which both return information like..

```
value| testdate  |
+--------+-------+
| 60 | 2014-09-20|
| 57 | 2014-09-21|
| 56 | 2014-09-22|
| 55 | 2014-09-23|
| 59 | 2014-09-24|
```

What I would like to do, is combine both sets of results into one (and then perform some maths like a ratio on the two numbers), so I want to end up with something like...

```
val1 | val2| ratio (val1/val2) | testdate   |
+----+-------------------------|------------+
| 60 | 140 | 0.42              | 2014-09-20 |
| 57 | 180 | 0.31              | 2014-09-21 |
| 56 | 190 | 0.29              | 2014-09-22 | 
| 55 | 10  | 5.5               | 2014-09-23 |
| 59 | 100 | 0.59              | 2014-09-24 |
```

I'm guessing I need a `JOIN` somewhere, but can't figure it, and how to use that value for some basic maths in there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the "**Self Join**" to join the 2 instances of same table. like below

```
SELECT s1.value, date_format( s1.statdate, "%Y-%m-%d" ) AS testdate
s2.value, date_format( s2.statdate, "%Y-%m-%d" ) AS testdate2,
(s1.value/s2.value) as ration
FROM stats s1, stats s2
WHERE s1.id = s2.id 
and s1.name LIKE 'myname1' AND s1.date >= "2014-09-20" and s1.date < "2014-09-24" 
and s2.name LIKE 'myname2' AND s2.date >= "2014-09-20" and s2.date < "2014-09-24" 
GROUP BY 2;
```

Comment: This is close and gives the right data, but how would I include calculating the ratio of the two values ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT date_format(statdate, '%Y-%m-%d') AS testdate,
       max(case when name = 'myname1' then value end) as val1,
       max(case when name = 'myname2' then value end) as val2,
       (max(case when name = 'myname1' then value end) /
        max(case when name = 'myname2' then value end)
       ) as ratio,
FROM stats
WHERE name in ('myname1', 'myname2') AND date >= '2014-09-20' and date < '2014-09-24'
GROUP BY date_format(statdate, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: I think this is looking good so far. Is it possible to clarify the max/case logic as to what that is doing, is it just to be able to access the value ?

Comment: Both of the answers give the right results, so I've upvoted both, but given the other the answer just as it feels more intuitive. I'm happy to be converted though if I can understand the pros of this technique in comparison.

Comment: @Ian . . . Personally, I think doing an extra join before the aggregation is *not* more intuitive, but to each his/her own.

Comment: I think if I understood the 'max' logic, I would likely feel different. Am happy to learn and change!

Comment: @Ian . . . The purpose of `max()` is to return one value from the aggregation.  You should learn how conditional aggregation works in this case.